# Bypassing variable declare in “Math.max”

Tags: javascript, variables

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
if...{var c = 3}; 
var d = Math.max(a, b, c);
```

How to get **Math.max** function work, if some of variables weren’t declared?
Choosing the biggest among existing.

Comment: How **exactly** do you expect it to *work* in such cases?

Comment: You should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property

Comment: Choosing the biggest among existing.

Comment: And declaring `c` outside the if-loop is not an option?

Answer (score 1):

Anything that you provide to `Math.max()` will attempt to be converted to a Number [MDN: `Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

> The largest of the given numbers. If at least one of the arguments
>   cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned.

You are asking that `undefined` be convereted to a Number which is difficult since it is undefined.  Consider that `0+undefined` returns `NaN` and `Number(undefined)` also returns `NaN`.

---

If you want `Math.max()` to **not** follow this rule of returning `NaN`, then you need to write your **own** `Math.max()`.

Also, per [Robby's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3558960/robby-cornelissen), it would be best to just filter out any `undefined` values or any other values that you don't want considered in the `max()`.

Maybe something like:

```js
function myMax(...args) {
  // Re write this filter to alter whatever you don't want to be considered by max()
  return Math.max(...args.filter(e => e !== undefined));
}

console.log(myMax(undefined, 1, 2)); // 2
console.log(myMax(-2, -1, undefined)); // -1
console.log(myMax(undefined)); // -Infinity
```

Comment: Probably better to filter out the `undefined` values. In your case, if the defined values are negative, `Math.max()` will still return a result of `0`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen You're right, I hadn't considered that test case.  Would probably be more performant as well.